# JAVASCRIPT editing headers to call api that returns json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, cors

I am trying to use an API that is hosted externally and also returns JSON data. I have tried editing the headers but I'm not entirely sure it is working because I am still getting a warning about not having the CORS header

**Source**

```
var url = "http://hkconsult.in/social_search/keyword_services.php?keyword=throat&callback=test";
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Origin":"http://hkconsult.in/social_search/keyword_services.php?keyword=throat&callback=test",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://hkconsult.in/social_search/keyword_services.php?keyword=throat&callback=test"
    }
}).done(function(data) { 
    document.getElementById('cool').innerHTML = data;
});
```

**[Firebug Headers](https://gyazo.com/c19dc3154a29e73b15235858ed64ab93)**
[image]

When opening the response for the "OPTIONS" url in firebug, it returns the data that I want. How do I use that data in javascript?

Comment: Just a tip, you should use `then` instead of `done`.

Answer (score 1):

The CORS are headers that the **server** should send you as a response to your request.

The `OPTIONS` request is performed by the browser to check those headers **prior** to performing your actual request.

You cannot get the result of that `OPTIONS` request because it happens outside the scope of your code.

If the server is not setup to send those headers, then your only option is to use a proxy page that will use a server-side script to perform the call on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are asking about how to parse the response JSON instead of `CORS` Issue.

```js
var data = {
 "0": {
  "keyword_name": "Sore throat",
  "id": "1787",
  "user_id": "3350988339",
  "user_name": "Nic",
  "user_screen_name": "Goldendevi",
  "user_profile_pic": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/840766770633945088/eRRoRZHv_normal.jpg",
  "user_location": "",
  "post_id": "864553159896838145",
  "post_text": "I'm so mad I have a fucking sore throat ðŸ™„",
  "post_geo_location": "0",
  "post_image": "",
  "post_date": "2017-05-16 20:48:30"
 },
 "1": {
  "keyword_name": "Sore throat",
  "id": "1788",
  "user_id": "63496454",
  "user_name": "mariana",
  "user_screen_name": "yugyeumie",
  "user_profile_pic": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/863802594132733952/ep0DtSoT_normal.jpg",
  "user_location": "jjp; ë§ ìŠ¨",
  "post_id": "864552988974747649",
  "post_text": "is it possible to die of a sore throat",
  "post_geo_location": "0",
  "post_image": "",
  "post_date": "2017-05-16 20:47:49"
 }
};
    
var res = Object.keys(data).map(item => {return data[item].keyword_name });

console.log(res);
```